# expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token in ordered_map()

Tags: c++

I want to insert paragraph or article content and process each word. Below I am trying to get each string and then get occurance of it. Finally I want word with max occurance. I am new to c++. Right now I have inserted statically two strings.
Which gives error `expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token`. Code is below:
`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,int> occurrences;
    occurrences s1;
    s1.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Hello",1));
    s1.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Hellos",2));

    //for ( auto it = occurrences.begin(); it != occurrences.end(); ++it )  this also gives same + additional " error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’" error
    for (std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = occurrences.begin();//Error is here
                                                    it != occurrences.end(); ////Error is here
                                                    ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "words :" << it->first << "occured" << it->second <<  "times";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`occurrences` is a type, not an object. You want to use the object `s1`.

Version 1:

```
for (auto it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); ++it)
```

Version 2:

```
for (std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); ++it)
```

Version 3:

```
for (auto pair : s1)
```

Comment: thanks, can you pleas tell me how can I insert string from user in above case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `s1.begin()` and `s1.end()`, not `occurrences.begin()` and `occurrences.end()`, since `occurrences` is a type, and `s1` is a variable of that type.

Comment: thanks, can you pleas tell me how can I insert string from user in above case? Simple can be done using getline() but here occurrence has two parameters I am confused!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wanting to do now. Are you trying to count how many times the words appear in standard input?